# How to create inhouse funnel analytics?

Tags: sql, database-design, hadoop, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I want to create in-house funnel analysis infrastructure. 
All the user activity feed information would be written to a database / DW of choice and then, when I dynamically define a funnel I want to be able to select the count of sessions for each stage in the funnel.

I can't find an example of creating such a thing anywhere. Some people say I should use Hadoop and MapReduce for this but I couldn't find any examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MapReduce is pretty simple:

Mapper reads row of a session in log file, its output is (stag-id, 1)

Set number of Reducers to be equal to the number of stages.

Reducer sums values for each stage. Like in wordcount example (which is a "Hello World" for Hadoop - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0).

You will have to set up a Hadoop cluster (or use Elastic Map Reduce on Amazon).

To define funnel dynamically you can use DistributedCache feature of Hadoop. To see results you will have to wait for MapReduce to finish (minimum dozens of seconds; or minutes in case of Amazon's Elastic MapReduce; the time depends on the amount of data and the size of your cluster).

Another solution that may give you results faster - use a database: select count(distinct session_id) group by stage from mylogs;

If you have too much data to quickly execute that query (it does a full table scan; HDD transfer rate is about 50-150MB/sec - the math is simple) - then you can use a distributed analytic database that runs over HDFS (distributed file system of Hadoop).

In this case your options are (I list here open-source projects only):

Apache Hive (based on MapReduce of Hadoop, but if you convert your data to Hive's ORC format - you will get results much faster).

Cloudera's Impala - not based on MapReduce, can return your results in seconds. For fastest results convert your data to Parquet format.

Shark/Spark  - in-memory distributed database.

Comment: Thanks! Will i be able to define the funnels dynamicaly and see the results right away  or will they have to be hard coded and ill need to wait some time until the results are available?

Comment: Wow thanks for that! There is still one end loose. The sum of each step will not work for me because i have funnels with reverse paths as well. For example: a->b->a (a and b are names of pages). in this case, using the sum will not work because in the third stage it will count all the pageviews of the first step. Do you have an idea how i can solve this? Thank again!

Comment: The output key of your Mappers should be StageId - as YOU define it, not necessarily PageId. E.g. "a-3" defines a stage to be page "a" accessed after two other pages on your site. Another example of stage definition: "c-d-a" can define a stage to be page "a" accessed after pages "c" and "d". The choice depends on the requirements, what you consider to be a unique stage. You should be able, of course, given a single record of your data to identify the stage, otherwise you need a "preprocessor" MapReduce to create such records.